Extracting symbols from mathabx causes warnings with newtxmath
I am taking a course in astrophysics and I want to use symbols of the solar system like Earth, the sun, etc like in this picture (from my homework assignment):

I found these symbols in the mathabx package, but this package also loads a lot of symbols I don't want. I read these 3 questions:

Packages for standard solar system (astronomical) symbols
How to extract only astronomical symbols from `mathabx` package?
Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font

I tried to extract the astronomical symbols and I came up with this MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm, libertine, varbb]{newtxmath} % Note the use of the `newtxmath` font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sun}           {0}{mathb}{"40}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mercury}       {0}{mathb}{"41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Venus}         {0}{mathb}{"42}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}         {0}{mathb}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mars}          {0}{mathb}{"44}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Jupiter}       {0}{mathb}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Saturn}        {0}{mathb}{"46}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uranus}        {0}{mathb}{"47}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Neptune}       {0}{mathb}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pluto}         {0}{mathb}{"49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varEarth}      {0}{mathb}{"4A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightmoon}     {0}{mathb}{"4C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fullmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newmoon}       {0}{mathb}{"4E}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Aries}         {0}{mathb}{"50}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Taurus}        {0}{mathb}{"51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gemini}        {0}{mathb}{"52}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Cancer}      {0}{mathb}{"53}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Leo}         {0}{mathb}{"54}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Virgo}       {0}{mathb}{"55}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Libra}         {0}{mathb}{"56}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Scorpio}       {0}{mathb}{"57}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sagittarius} {0}{mathb}{"58}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Capricornus} {0}{mathb}{"59}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Aquarius}    {0}{mathb}{"59}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pisces}      {0}{mathb}{"59}

\begin{document}
\[ M_{\Sun} = \SI{1.989e33}{\gram} \]
\[ M_{\Earth} = \SI{5.9722e27}{\gram} \]
\end{document}

Compiling the document succeeds and gives the expected results:

However, this gives me warnings:

These warnings come from the newtxmath package. Commenting it out makes everything compile without warnings. I like the newtxmath font and I usually use it globally. I just want to get the astronomical symbols from mathabx. How can I fix these warnings? Alternatively, is there a different package/font I can get the astronomical symbols from without getting these warnings?
I am compiling with VSCode with the Latex Workshop extension with latexmk (lualatex) if it's helpful to know.

You avoid the warnings by defining the fonts to be fully scalable; mathabx still uses the “fixed sizes” that were needed in the olden times when only bitmap fonts were available. Since newtx uses noninteger font sizes, the warnings appear.
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% avoid an annoying warning
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm, libertine, varbb]{newtxmath} % Note the use of the `newtxmath` font
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sun}           {0}{mathb}{"40}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mercury}       {0}{mathb}{"41}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Venus}         {0}{mathb}{"42}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}         {0}{mathb}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mars}          {0}{mathb}{"44}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Jupiter}       {0}{mathb}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Saturn}        {0}{mathb}{"46}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uranus}        {0}{mathb}{"47}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Neptune}       {0}{mathb}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pluto}         {0}{mathb}{"49}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varEarth}      {0}{mathb}{"4A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightmoon}     {0}{mathb}{"4C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fullmoon}      {0}{mathb}{"4D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newmoon}       {0}{mathb}{"4E}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Aries}         {0}{mathb}{"50}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Taurus}        {0}{mathb}{"51}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gemini}        {0}{mathb}{"52}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Cancer}      {0}{mathb}{"53}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Leo}         {0}{mathb}{"54}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Virgo}       {0}{mathb}{"55}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Libra}         {0}{mathb}{"56}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Scorpio}       {0}{mathb}{"57}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sagittarius} {0}{mathb}{"58}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Capricornus} {0}{mathb}{"59}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Aquarius}    {0}{mathb}{"59}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pisces}      {0}{mathb}{"59}

\begin{document}
\[ M_{\Sun} = \SI{1.989e33}{\gram} \]
\[ M_{\Earth} = \SI{5.9722e27}{\gram} \]
\end{document}



This doesn't work, but I found that using the anyfontsize package solves the warnings.

@ShaiAvr Sorry, but it does work.

It didn't work on my MacBook yesterday. Strangely, I am now trying it on my Windows desktop and there are no warnings at all, even without the fix
